# How to Pass Dropdownlist Value to Sql Query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass dropdownlist which select the value and pass to the SQL query,But I don't have idea that how can I do to the next step.

View:

```
@{ 
List<SelectListItem> List = new List<SelectListItem>();
minList.Add(new SelectListItem {
    Text=DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1).ToString(),
    Value="1"
});
minList.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2).ToString(),
    Value = "2"
});
minList.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-3).ToString(),
    Value = "3"
});}@Html.DropDownList( "Min",List, "Select")
```

SQL Statement(C#):

```
string sqlStr = "Select * From Data WHERE Time BETWEEN @A AND @B";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, conn);

DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
SelectListItem min = new SelectListItem();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@A", min.Value));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@B", now));
```

Comment: You need to post the value of the selected option in a form to a controller method which calls the query.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller Action Method, you can use FormCollection or **Request.Form** to get dropdown value.

```
string strDDLValue = Request.Form["minList"].ToString();
```

Comment: You can pass the string strDdlValue for @A parameter replacing min.value. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Because I put SQL statement code in the Model，So... I have no idea What can I do...And then I learn MVC for a few day

Comment: Can you please show, how are you calling your Model method?

Comment: Like this
      
        `private Repository repository = new Repository();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {  
            var data = this.repository.GetData().ToList();
            return View(data);
        } `

Comment: And your GetData() have the SQL statements?

Comment: Can you make GetData() method to accept one parameter where you can pass strDDLValue that can be used in your model?